# Get Intent from user response in a waterfall dialog

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am working with LuisDialog. For a specific intent, I have a waterfall dialog to get information from user. In this process, I want to parse user's sentence/response with LUIS.

```
luisDialog.on('orderItem', [
  function (session, args) {
    builder.Prompts.text(session, "Please enter your item ID:");
  },
  function (session, results) {
    // parse user's response with LUIS
    // User can text: "1245" or "my item ID is 1245"
    // Need to get "1245" as item_number which is an entity in LUIS train model
  }
]);
```

Is there any ways to achieve this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is a way to do it directly with node.js. However, LUIS has a REST interface. This would enable you to call the service and manually process the JSON returned to get the data you need.

So you can make a call to

> https://api.projectoxford.ai/luis/v1/application?id=applicationid&subscription-key=subscriptionkey&q=my
>   item ID is 1245

using your REST client of choice. You'll get a JSON response back that you can process to extract the data you need. applicationid and subscriptionkey should be replaced with the appropriate values for your Luis Model

Comment: yes, that is a way to do. But I just wonder if botframework supports api/method to do that. It will be better.

Comment: I'm not sure there is, other than using another LuisDialog to do it. Another question to consider is whether you need to do it. If you ask 'Please Enter Your Item ID' I believe it is reasonable to assume the user will simply enter the number '1234' instead of 'my item id is 1234'. Why would they do extra typing? Unless you want them to be able to enter 'one thousand two hundred and thirty four' in which case Luis would be of use.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.

```
bot.dialog("/schedule", [
    (session, args, next)=>{
        builder.Prompts.text(session,"When do you prefer new appoitment");
     },
    (session,results,next)=>{
        session.sendTyping();
        builder.LuisRecognizer.recognize(results.response,model, (err,intents,entities)=>{
                if(err){
                    console.log("Some error occurred in calling LUIS");
                }
                console.log(intents);
                console.log("==================");
                console.log(entities);
        });

    }
]);
```

Comment: How can I assign to a new variable called session.dialogData.myEntities the object containing all the entities recognized by the LuisRecognizer.recognize() method? I need to store this entities somewhere so I can use them again in the waterfall before the dialog ends...